# Converting raster into polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS.

I am working with a raster which basically shows like 5 colors. I chose some values with the raster calc in QGIS so I have now 5 different TIFFs where each "color" is defined as 1. All I want to do now is to convert these in a vector shape to merge them back together and classify these different colors the way I want.

I googled some time and found out I have to convert from floating to int somehow. This did't work to.

Is there maybe even an easier way to just define these 5 colors in the original rasterset as values from 1-5 and then export/convert it to a vectorshape?

Can deliver screenshots tomorrow when I am back at work.

Answer (score -1):

In Qgis, try using using Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize (Raster to Vector)

Comment: we tried it, but it doesnt work. 
We transferred it now to our IT section :P

Comment: Is there a way to make this plugin use the exact values in the raster symbology classification?  I have 3 classes but it is bumping my values like 5.5 up to 6 but one of the symbology breaks needs to be at 5.5, so i lose resolution when they become polygons though they are represented properly in the raster symbology.